# Convert number from DB to a decimal in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, number-formatting

In a table the amounts are saved without decimal points.

```
1 = 0.01, 10 = 0.10, 100 = 1.00, 1000 = 10.00.
```

I want to display it normal in vb.net how do I convert that to a regular decimal format?

Comment: sounds right... I didn't think of that. there's no build in function to do that for me?

Comment: @TheZ please post it as a answer so I could accept it and close it. Thanks

Comment: @Ezi Guffa has a more detailed answer, I'd go with that :)

Comment: Note: I took the liberty of changing the title of your question, so it more clearly reflects what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value is stored as a string in the database, you parse it to a number:

```
Dim n as Integer = Int32.Parse(theString)
```

Then just convert the number to floating point, and divide by 100:

```
Dim d as Double = Convert.ToDouble(n) / 100.0
```

As the `/` operator always does floating point division in VB, you can let it to an implicit conversion:

```
Dim d as Dobule = n / 100.0
```

Comment: Except instead of using double, you should be using decimal.

Comment: @jmoreno: Yes, if you need that specific data type. There is nothing in the question that indicates that.